# Tabular report and duplicate rows

Tags: reporting, analytics

I am confused with this basic reporting issue:

I have a simple criteria:

[image]

I would expect to see only unique records in my view/ export, but I see duplicate rows of the same record.

Irrespective of what I chose either  "My Teams opportunities" / "All Opportunities" I see duplicate rows, is the report including my visibility + my subordinates who can see this record making the count to 4 instead of one unique record?

Please clarify what I am missing here !!!

[image]

Comment: I dont think visibility will double records .Its weird .Your screenshot is so tiny for me to view

Comment: What Report Type are you using?

Comment: @AlexTennant Tabular

Comment: I meant is this an "Opportunities" report, or "Opportunities with Contact Roles"... etc.

Comment: @AlexTennant oh sorry its a custom report type

Comment: Then it looks like whatever child object you are using has multiple records for that particular Opportunity, in which case the Opportunity details will be repeated on each line however the fields that correspond to the child objects should be different on each line.

Comment: Dang Alex you are right, this totally makes sense. Can you post it as an answer I will accept it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mentioned you are using a custom Report Type with Opportunity as the parent object.

If an Opportunity has multiple child records under it then the Opportunity rows on your reports will be repeated for each child object, for example, if your Opportunity had 5 of your child object, the Opportunity fields will be repeated 5 times.

However, if you look at the columns which correspond to the fields on your child object you should notice that each of those lines has different values and refers to a different record.

This is similar behaviour to if you do a left join in SQL and more than one record on the right side of the join matches the left side.